# Automate changing Statement into Prepared Statement programmatically through Java ( In source code )

Tags: java, automation

I have been assigned a task for automating the conversion of statements into prepared statements for security purpose. Since it's a repetitive task, I want to automate it.

for example

```
public String getEmployee(Connection connection, Long id , Long groupId) {
    
    String result = "";
    
    try {

        Statement stmt = connection.createStatement();
        
        String query = "select * from employee"
                + " where id = " + id ;  // flaw 1
        
        if(groupId != null) {
            query += " and group_id = " + groupId; // flaw 2 
        }
        
        ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(query);
   }
```

I want to remove the flaws with :

```
public String getEmployee(Connection connection, Long id , Long groupId) {
    
    String result = "";
    
    try {

        String query = "select * from employee"
                + " where id = ? ";
        
        if(groupId != null) {
            query += " and group_id = ? ";
        }

        PreparedStatement stmt = connection.prepareStatement(query);
        stmt.setLong(parameterIndex++, id);
        stmt.setLong(parameterIndex++, groupId);
        ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery();
    }
```

I need to write a java code, that can replace these Statements with Prepared Statements.

**Input will be the java file.**

I tried a lot, but couldn't find out a possible solution to this problem.

Can you please help me by guiding me, if it's feasible.

Comment: Statements and surrounding code can get very complex so unless you really know that this isn't the case you shouldn't attempt that. Doing it automatically is hard and likely to introduce errors. Since there could also be other security issues I'd not trust any automatically refactored code but would want an experienced developer to actually look at it. - That being said, I want to commend your project lead (the one giving you the task) for approving this task but I'd also say that prepared statements not having been used in the first place was a bad start (note for the future: don't do that).

Comment: Use IntelliJ, the best Java IDE.  That's your best hope.

Comment: I would recommend making those query Strings static and final.  You'll have a lot less boilerplate code if you use Spring JdbcTemplate.  Add Maven and Spring Boot to your project and you'll do yourself a favor.

Comment: I am using IntelliJ only to edit the code, but there are several files and with automation, it may be possible to process 1500+ files, automatically, instead of a manual effort.